# how can i get a value of a variable from one php file to another php file

Tags: php

i want to get the value of variable $code on index.php file but $code is in images.php. I included images.php in index.php. how do i get the value on index.php file without using session.

Comment: We're not magic, it's hard to tell where your going wrong (if at all).. If you don't show your code

Comment: Use SESSION or send with url GET method. or include this page to desired page

Comment: @Salim Not in all cases, an include carries over the variables aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the php include function,

you can use `include 'file.txt';` if the file is in the same directory.
or `..\folder\file.txt` to go back directories.

but instead of include you can also set a session variable. where you start a session and store variables in the session, these can you retrieve on other php files but you need to start the session on that file aswell.
this works like:

`session_start(); // start the session 
$_SESSION['views']=1;`

this variable can then be returend on the other php file like: `session_start();
$local_variable = $_SESSION['views'];`

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the file you have access to the variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

When you include a file, it's like the whole code being rewritten in the main file. Therefore, if you include "images.php" with the variable $code in "index.php" , $code will be available to use in "index.php".

Answer (score 0):

**images.php**

```
<?php

$code = "Test";

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

include("images.php");

echo $code;

?>
```

Output in page index.php

```
Test
```